# Wifi suddenly not working on thinkpad, in both Manjaro and parrot linux

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, network-interface, manjaro

I boot up the laptop one day and wireless is not working. The wireless led on the laptop is green, showing it's working. In bios, it is enabled.

But Linux does not see any kind of wireless interface, only Ethernet. Can't give the terminal output for `ifconfig` since I'm on my tablet. It only shows `enp8s0`, which is ether, and lo, which I'm not sure what it is.

No wireless, it's not showing up in `rfkill` so it's not blocked there, and it's not stopped by the thinkpad laptop buttons either. It just plain up and vanished.

All commands suggested in the comments ascertain the same thing I did by way of ifconfig and others: no wireless interface detected.

Comment: Welcome to U&L please add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: No output. Does nothing, ran it normally and as sudo

Comment: Run `lspci` to get more info about the wifi card

Comment: Check you have not accidental hit the physical "WiFi" switch on the side of the Laptop.

Comment: No wireless displayed, ends with Ethernet. @tigger Wireless is not stopped by way of laptop button, and the laptop has an LCD that shows it as working.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? If not, try `sudo service NetworkManager restart`

Comment: Service command not found

Comment: Can you edit your question and show `dmesg | egrep -i 'net|firm|fail|error'` and for sure ` systemctl --failed` also `journalctl -b -p err..alert`

Comment: I cannot paste from terminal as I am writing here on s tablet, the output on both of those gave me info on Ethernet and Bluetooth, but nothing on wifi

Comment: The Wifi driver is not installed

Comment: Well it was working in both Manjaro and parrot os, and it stopped working overnight. What's the chance of two different installs losing their drivers at the same time overnight

Comment: Check the wifi diriver with `lspci -knn` then reload the kernel module with `rmmod` and `modprobe`

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly a Debian 8 related problem. Ensure your GPU proprietary drivers installed properly, then open your terminal and try doing a full system upgrade as a Super-User `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

After which on your terminal, you can run these again
To find your wireless interface and bring it up:

```
sudo ip a

sudo iwconfig

sudo ip link set wlan0 up
```

To Scan for available networks and get network details:

```
sudo iwlist scan
```